# iPad Mini can't open apps

Tags: ios, ipad

I've had my iPad for a year now. When I tried to open Safari and my iPad froze and I came back to the home screen. This started after the new software update. Since then no apps will open, not even the App Store. I've tried restarting it and let it die (letting the battery run out) and recharging, but it didn't help.

How can I open apps on my iPad?

Comment: Which 'new' software update?

Comment: Have you tried an hard-reset? Press Home + Lock button simultaneously in 10 seconds and then release them. Your iPad will reboot and you won't lose any data.

Comment: Setting started open a while ago so it's now working well it started working a long time ago just for got to post on here

Answer (score 1):

- As 'Dempa' said in comments, you should do a hard-reset:
  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559 <- "Force Restart"
- If this does not solve the problem, you should back up your info in iTunes (Assuming that you cant open Settings app):
  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977 <- "iTunes Backup"
- And if restoring doesnt solve the problem, you will have to go into an Apple Service Shop/Center, however they are called in your country, and ask for technical assistance.

**Im pretty sure the HARD RESET step is what you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tryed that

Comment: And I posting this from my laptop

Comment: Have you tried a restore?

Comment: It's working now